# how to call NPP_StreamAsFile

Tags: npapi

Hi I have a plugin.dll which contains this all npp functions I have embeded it in my chrome plugin successfully but I dont know how to call this  NPP_StreamAsFile function from my javascript. I dont have any idea. There are so many parameters to pass which I dont have any idea about . please help me.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't call `NPP_StreamAsFile()` yourself, the browser does. There are three types of functions for the NPAPI:

- `NP_` - the plugin module entry functions etc.
- `NPN_` - the browser interface, the plugin calls them
- `NPP_` - the plugins interface, the browser calls them

You also can't just access `NPP` functions directly from scripts, you'd have to provide a scriptable interface for your plugin.

From the plugin side, the process looks like following:

- first, the plugin needs to call [`NPN_NewStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_NewStream) or [`NPN_GetURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_GetURL) to create a stream
- if that worked, the browser calls [`NPP_NewStream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPP_NewStream), you have to set `*stype` to `NP_ASFILE` or `NP_ASFILEONLY`
- if you specified `NP_ASFILE` and the file is not local, stream data is progressively delivered via `NPP_Write()`/`NPP_WriteReady()`
- when the stream is complete, the browser calls [`NPP_StreamAsFile()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPP_StreamAsFile).